# Android postgresql connection

Tags: java, android, database, postgresql, jdbc

I want to connect to the database on my computer from my phone. I use JDBC for this. But I can not make a connection. I can connect to the database with a different SQL Client application. I have added the postgresql jdbc driver project.

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.40:5432/postgres","postgres","1");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        txt.setText("Connection failed :"+e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        txt.setText("Library not found");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
    });
```

Error code:

```
    E/org.postgresql.Driver: Unexpected connection error: 
                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
                         at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
                         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
                         at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:475)
                         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:861)
                         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
                         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
                         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
                         at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
                         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)
                         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)
                         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
                         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
                         at yube.com.databaseconnection.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5307)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:831)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you help me.

Comment: can you connect with localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says that you try to establish a network connection on the main thread. This is not allowed in strict mode because this would make your app unresponsive.

You have two options:

1. Use a new Thread or AsyncTask to connect to your database
2. Modify the thread policy (only recommended to test the connection process)

   `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build())`